# Load all data from local database

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am using react-native-gifted-chat(https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat) to create a chat interface on my app, I want to load messages from my database.

I am using realm, and I am able to load the data but my code below loads only the first row of the data. I want to be able to load all the data from the database.

```
    let chatData = realmDatabase.objects(DatabaseTableNames.chatTable);

    let data=[];

    for (let message of chatData ){

      data =  [{
                        _id: message.chatUniqueID,
                        text: message.msgBody,
                        createdAt: (new Date()).getTime(),
                        user: {
                           _id: message.chatUniqueID,
                           name: message.senderName
                       }
                 } ]


    }



   console.log(data)
```

I want to be able to load all the data from the database not only the first row, like the sample below.

```
   [
      {
        _id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000),
        text:
          "It uses the same design as React, letting you compose a rich mobile UI from declarative components https://facebook.github.io/react-native/",
        createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 31, 17, 20, 0)),
        user: {
          _id: 1,
          name: "Developer"
        },

      },

      {
        _id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000),
        text: "React Native lets you build mobile apps using only JavaScript",
        createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 30, 17, 20, 0)),
        sent: true,
        received: true,
        user: {
          _id: 2,
          name: "Developer"
      },

      }
    ];
```

Comment: So console.log(data) outputs only one row? Are there any default limits in realm database call? Does it get from database all, or only this one row (maybe it is only output not fetch problem)?

Comment: Yes, It gets all data from the realm, I just realised its not a fetch problem but the output. Because when the `console.log(data)` is placed inside the `for` function it prints all the data

Comment: @George question behind the scenes, this chat will be one to one "private"?  why are you using a realm? and if I using firebase as a backend in the whole app I need to use realm in the chat or just do it in firebase?

Comment: @DevAS yes Its a one on one chat. Which database to use is solely your choice, you can use firebase, But I prefer to use realm, socket.io with mysql database because I have a 100% control over what I am doing unlike firebase.

Comment: yeah, I'm planning to build specific chat in my app, but I don't have an idea about how to manipulate the message between one to one if you have time can you provide me an article about this point @George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `data = [{...}]` in the for loop, will assign the last value of `message` to `data`. To get all the values, you need to [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the items in the `data` array. You can do it like this:

```
let chatData = realmDatabase.objects(DatabaseTableNames.chatTable);

let data=[];

for (let message of chatData ){
    data.push({
        _id: message.chatUniqueID,
        text: message.msgBody,
        createdAt: (new Date()).getTime(),
        user: {
            _id: message.chatUniqueID,
            name: message.senderName
        }
    });
}

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Happy to help :)